# The meaning of the particle に in this sentence

Tags: particle-に

医者に薬をもらいました。

I couldn't understand the meaning of に here.

Would it be: "I received the medicine from the doctor."?

Comment: What is the context of this sentence?

Comment: With no context, what would be a good translation for you?

Comment: With people, my general sense is to consider に as marking the recipient of a given action. In this case, I would go with something like "The doctor got some medicine"

Comment: ^ `The doctor got some medicine` Hmm I think it's "I got some medicine from the doctor" or "The doctor gave me some medicine" (or more literally: "I was given some medicine by the doctor"?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> http://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%AB%20%23particle 
>   5. by; from

I had to look this up.

医者から薬をもらいました。-- is more like English, but

医者に薬をもらいました。-- is more characteristically Jp.

> http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/166083/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%AB/ 
>   10 受け身・使役の相手・対象を表す。「犬―かまれた」「巣箱を子供たち―作らせる」

Dog bit me. -- ( Doctor gave me. )

I was bitten by the dog. --  ( I was given [ the drug ] by the doctor. )

> http://people.ucalgary.ca/~xyang/kobun/6-2-4.htm 
>    （八）受身・使役の相手を示す。「風―吹かれる」「友人に言わせる」

[Something is] blown by the wind.